# remove visual composer from one single page wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a paid plugin "Visual Composer". I want to remove the visual composer from one specific page. But I have tried from screen options and from acf too. Still visual composer still appears.

Answer (score 1):

It can be filtered when WP pulls all active plugins. We check if it's admin side and if the current admin page is correct, then check the URL to see if post with ID **`2`** (Sample Page) is being edited, and finally remove the plugin from the option list:

```
add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', function ( $option ) 
{  
    global $pagenow;
    if( 'post.php' !== $pagenow || !is_admin() )
        return $option;

    if( !isset( $_GET['post'] ) || '2' !== $_GET['post'] )
        return $option;

    return array_diff( $option, array( 'js_composer/js_composer.php' ) );
});
```

Comment: it actually deactivate the plugin but does not remove the buttons!

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove the buttons via javascript or CSS by targeting the .composer-switch class.

```
.composer-switch {
 display:none;
}
```

This would remove the buttons on that page if you combine it with the PHP at top.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "remove visual composer" on the front-end view you can use this plugin: [Plugin organizer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-organizer/)

Just install, activate the option "Selective plugin loading" as on the screen capture [image: Plugin organizer]

And go thru wordpress admin to the page you want to disable Visual composer, scroll down to find the Plugin organizer options" and disable "visual composer" for that page just dragging and dropping to one side or another. You can do it for any page you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `vc_is_valid_post_type_be` filter to completely disable the backend and frontend editor like so:

```
// Disable WPBakery on certain pages
add_filter( 'vc_is_valid_post_type_be', 'disable_wpbakery', 10, 2 );
function disable_wpbakery( $enabled, $post_type ) {
    global $post;

    // Replace with the condition of your choice
    if ( in_array( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true ), [
        'my-template.php',
        'other-template.php'
    ] ) ) {
        // Optionally disable the classic editor
        //remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'editor' );
        return false;
    }

    return $enabled;
}
```